# Set value of nested object in JHipster/Angular

Tags: angular, jhipster

In a JHipster Application I have the following entities and relationships:

```
 entity Request {
        description String required
    }
    
    entity RequestPerson {
        firstName String required,
        lastName String required
    }
    
    relationship OneToOne {
      Request{affectedPerson} to RequestPerson,
    }
```

The generated Angular Component for editing a Request contains the description field of the Request as well as the id of the RequestPerson record (from demo data).

I like to automatically create a new RequestPerson object when creating a new Request (frontend-side) to make it able to edit the fields of the RequestPerson when creating a new Request.

What is a good way to implement this? In the RequestMapper I already removed the @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) annotation for the RequestPerson attribute so the the http-response of loading an existing Request already contains the complete RequestPerson object. But if I only add the fields of RequestPerson to the Angular Component, nothing happens.

```
<input
                  id="field_affectedPerson_firstName"
                  data-cy="affectedPerson.firstName"
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  name="affectedPerson.firstName"
                  formControlName="affectedPerson.firstName"
                />
```

Thanks for your advises!

Comment: Best way is to create a DTO and to manage persistence in service layer in backend.

Comment: I want to enable the user to provide Information about the child object directly when creating a new Request object. Since this will be initialized in the frontend, the DTO will not affected this process, isn't it?

Comment: I'm speaking about manually creating a DTO and its resource controler, so you can do whatever you want. This is a way to avoid exposing your data model (entities) in UI which is usually a sign of a poor user experience.

Comment: Is there an end to end example for Jhipster with angular?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but there's nothing different in Angular code and REST controller.

Comment: Ok, I unverstand. The correct flow would be: 1. User click on "New Request" 2. The Request will be initialized in the backend instead of the frontend (persited or transient)? What is, if I have a one2many Relationship? Does I have a Button (create child) in the Details component of the parent that triggers a creation of the child object in the backend and than the User populates the fields of the child?

Comment: In frontend you have a view model (call it `RequestSubmission`) for your form that combines all your objects then frontend posts it to a `RequestSubmissionResource`  controler in your backend, the controler validates input and then calls `RequestSubmissionService` that instantiates all entities from it and call their respective repositories within a transaction. The key point here is that `RequestSubmission` is not entity, you can't find it in your database, it's just an object that exists to transfer the information: a DTO. It's like when you are filling a form paper in some administration.

Comment: I did not understand your question about buttons. I guess you should get away from thinking with a CRUD REST API.